# What is the Apps.ppkg file about?

Tags: windows-10

I'm looking at the disk usage using WinDirStat, and a sizable chunk (3.5 GB) of my SSD is taken by this file:

```
C:\Recovery\Customizations\Apps.ppkg
```

My question is simply that I would like to *understand* what this file is about?

A secondary (but less important) question is if it's safe (and how to go about) to remove that file, given that I don't mind Recovery mode much, since I can easily re-install my laptop and get my files from source control and backups or network drives.

I'm working on a 2017 Dell XPS Laptop with Windows 10 Pro.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

.ppkg files are [provisioning packages](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/provisioning-packages/provisioning-packages):

> A provisioning package (.ppkg) is a container for a collection of
>   configuration settings. With Windows 10, you can create provisioning
>   packages that let you quickly and efficiently configure a device
>   without having to install a new image.
>
> Provisioning packages are simple enough that with a short set of
>   written instructions, a student or non-technical employee can use them
>   to configure their device. This can result in a significant reduction
>   in the time required to configure multiple devices in your
>   organization.

So it looks like Dell used it to pre-install some apps without modifying their large Deployment image because Setup looks into that folder for ppkg files:

> The provisioning engine always applies provisioning packages persisted
>   in the `C:\Recovery\Customizations` folder on the OS partition. When
>   the provisioning engine applies provisioning packages in the
>   `%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Provisioning` folder, certain runtime setting
>   applications, such as the setting to install and configure Windows
>   apps, may be extended past the OOBE pass and continually be processed
>   in the background when the device gets to the desktop. Settings for
>   configuring policies and certain crucial system configurations are
>   always be completed before the first point at which they must take
>   effect.

Make a backup of the file on external storage and try to delete it.